# Azure Pipeline - The term 'Get-AzKeyVaultSecret' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-powershell, azure-keyvault, azure-pipelines-yaml, powershell-cmdlet

I have an Azure Pipeline which runs the following command to install the Az.KeyVault module, before going on to run another script (list-keyvault-secrets.ps1) where the installed KeyVault module gets called.

[image]

The module gets installed successfully, however when the powershell script that follows gets run, the pipeline fails and displays the below error message.

[image]

This is an example of one of the lines of code where the Get-AzKeyVaultSecret command is called:

```
$plainTxtSecret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $srckvName -Name $name -AsPlainText
```

Any idea what could be causing this error and how I can resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use the [AzurePowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-powershell?view=azure-devops&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203) Azure DevOps Task.
Here an example:

```
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: my-arm-service-connection
    scriptType: filePath
    scriptPath: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\myscript.ps1
    scriptArguments:
      -Arg1 val1 `
      -Arg2 val2 `
      -Arg3 val3
    azurePowerShellVersion: latestVersion
    pwsh: true
```